# Update Value not Contained in Subquery Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to update a personnel table with a locationID. However, I only want to update the location when a person has only 1 address.

I tried to put together a subquery. However, if I include the locationUD from Address in the select statement, then it gives me everyone, even people with 2 actual addresses (because they aren't living at an address more than once.)

How can I rewrite my query to update the locationID only in situations where a person appears in the subquery once without including the locationID in the select statement?

```
update p set locationID = n2.locationID 
--select *
from
  Personnel p
  inner join (select p.personID, 
      count(*) AS 'Num of Households/Addresses'
      --select *
  from Person pe
  inner join Address a on a.personID = pe.personID 
  group by pe.personID
  having count(*) = 1) n2 on n2.personID = p.personID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trick.  If there is only one match, then `min()` or `max()` get you the value from that row:

```
update p
    set locationID = n2.locationID 
from Personnel p inner join
     (select a.personID, max(a.locationid) as locationid
      from Address a 
      group by a.personID
      having count(*) = 1
     ) n2
     on n2.personID = p.personID;
```

Notice that the `person` table is not needed in the subquery.  You can just use the value from the `Address` table.